# finding the total number of records for a given location

Tags: php, mysql, aggregate

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT sku, quantity, inventory.isbn13, author, title, pub_date, binding, 
      defect.defect, source, location from inventory
      LEFT JOIN location ON inventory.location_id = location.location_id
      LEFT JOIN source ON inventory.source_id = source.source_id
      LEFT JOIN book ON inventory.isbn13 = book.isbn13
      LEFT JOIN defect ON inventory.defect_id = defect.defect_id
      LEFT JOIN book_condition ON book_condition.condition_id = defect.condition_id
      WHERE quantity > '0' and location.location_id >= '986' and location.location_id <= '989'
      ORDER BY inventory.location_id, sku
```

Which works perfectly, but now I need to show a total number of books for each location id. For example location_id 986 has 17 books, location_id 987 has 34 books etc.
do I need to run a second query to get this information or is there a way to do this in the query I have?
Thanks
Jim

Comment: do you want this information in the context of your inventory or in a more general context "how many books is there in this location"?

Comment: I need to show the total number of books for each location selected (in this case the 986 - 989) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go:

```
SELECT
    sku, 
    quantity, 
    inventory.isbn13, 
    author, 
    title, 
    pub_date, 
    binding, 
    defect.defect, 
    source, 
    location,
    t.cnt
FROM 
    inventory i
        INNER JOIN 
            (
            SELECT
                inventory.location_id,
                COUNT(book.isbn13) as `cnt`
            FROM inventory
                  LEFT JOIN book ON inventory.isbn13 = book.isbn13
            GROUP BY inventory.location_id
            ) t ON t.location_id = i.location_id
        INNER JOIN location l       ON i.location_id = l.location_id
        LEFT JOIN source            ON i.source_id = source.source_id
        LEFT JOIN defect            ON i.defect_id = defect.defect_id
        LEFT JOIN book_condition    ON book_condition.condition_id = defect.condition_id
WHERE 
    i.quantity > '0' 
AND l.location_id >= '986' 
AND l.location_id <= '989'
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in testing your example, but when I run it I get an sql syntax error at *)as 'cnt'.  I am not sure what the book.* means, can you please explain a little so I can correct the error and try the code again?. Thanks

Comment: book is the book table, I'm still wondering why there's a syntax error, stll checking...

Comment: I made a few changes, and changed book.* to book.title and it seems to work.  I still need to verify the math, but on first glance it looks close.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: ok cool, I was just figuring this out, using book.isbn13 also would be safer, if your title field is nullable.

Comment: I had just tried that as well since some of the titles are null.  Looks like a winner to me.  I did need to add in a left join book ON i.isbn13 = book.isbn13, just an FYI.  Thanks Again for the help.

Comment: oooh sorry, I wasn't sure since the fields of the select part were not prefixed so I didn't really know from where they belonged, my fault!! Thanks for the vote. rgds.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use Group By and Count()

(it would be a different query of-course)

When you use Count() and Group by - make sure you don't include in the Select columns that cannot be aggregated...

Answer (score 0):

It could probably be done using a SQL query, but you can also do it using PHP code. Loop through the results and count the totals, something like this:

```
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $location_count [$row['location_id']]++;
}
echo $location_count [986]; // outputs 17
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*), sku, quantity, inventory.isbn13, author, title, pub_date, binding, 
      defect.defect, source, location from inventory
      LEFT JOIN location ON inventory.location_id = location.location_id
      LEFT JOIN source ON inventory.source_id = source.source_id
      LEFT JOIN book ON inventory.isbn13 = book.isbn13
      LEFT JOIN defect ON inventory.defect_id = defect.defect_id
      LEFT JOIN book_condition ON book_condition.condition_id = defect.condition_id
      WHERE quantity > '0' and location.location_id >= '986' and location.location_id <= '989'
      ORDER BY inventory.location_id, sku
      GROUP BY location.location_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the post, but this returns only the last location with the total number of records in the query results.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the MySql function 'Found_rows', without affect or change your query, take a look to my local example.

```
mysql> select * from actor where actor_id>190;
+----------+------------+-------------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name   | last_update         |
+----------+------------+-------------+---------------------+
|      191 | GREGORY    | GOODING     | 2012-05-22 15:12:26 |
|      192 | JOHN       | SUVARI      | 2012-05-22 15:12:26 |
|      193 | BURT       | TEMPLE      | 2012-05-22 15:12:26 |
|      194 | MERYL      | ALLEN       | 2012-05-22 15:12:26 |
|      195 | JAYNE      | SILVERSTONE | 2012-05-22 15:12:26 |
|      196 | BELA       | WALKEN      | 2012-05-22 15:12:26 |
|      197 | REESE      | WEST        | 2012-05-22 15:12:26 |
|      198 | MARY       | KEITEL      | 2012-05-22 15:12:26 |
|      199 | JULIA      | FAWCETT     | 2012-05-22 15:12:26 |
|      200 | THORA      | TEMPLE      | 2012-05-22 15:12:26 |
|      205 | 1          | 2           | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|      206 | a          | b           | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+----------+------------+-------------+---------------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select FOUND_ROWS();
+--------------+
| FOUND_ROWS() |
+--------------+
|           12 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

this function will give you the rows number of the last query.